# "Single instance application": Multiple instances in Windows 2008 terminal server environment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008, terminal-services

I have a small VB.NET application to handles a custom URL protocol. It is set up in Visual Studio with the option to "Make single instance application". This has worked for hundreds of installations, but a recent customer is using Windows Terminal Server 2008, and it is launching multiple copies of the application.  It does not seem to sense that it is already running for a specific user.  BTW -
 Multiple users can run it without problems in different sessions.

[image]

Is there some sort of setting on the Windows Terminal server that could cause this?

We have installed the application using install mode, and with the administrator ID.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: So, to clarify, the design is that it should only run a single instance per logon session, but in fact on this particular server you are getting multiple instances in the same logon session?  Or might the problem be that the same user is logging into multiple sessions and is able to run it once in each of those sessions?

Comment: A single user will get two instances running in a single session.  It is a URL Protocol handler, so it is invoked when a user clicks on a link in a browser.   Any subsequent link should be routed to the running instances, vs starting a second instance.

Comment: After some research, it sounds like VS used .NET Remoting to accomplish this feature, allowing the processes to sense one another.  Thus, it may be related to a firewall or anti-virus setting.

Comment: The Windows firewall isn't supposed to affect internal traffic, so that's less likely.  (Still worth investigating, just in case.)  Could certainly be anti-virus.  Could also be something Terminal Services is doing - unless you already have other customers successfully using the software with Terminal Services / Remote Desktop Services?  Might also be worth investigating whether the choice of browser makes any difference.